# Reading data with DHTxx.Dht11

Tags: c#, .net, iot

Im trying to reproduce the IoT example from a .NET stream, but since my temperature sensor is a module and has a data pin, I tried to do it how I can find examples for similar builds.

What I wondered is, the class [DHTxx.Dht11](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/iot.device.dhtxx.dht11) has no read method. So I have no idea how to actively read the data or if it keeps reading if connected the right way and I just have to grab the latest value from the proiperties.

here my code:

```
int _pinSensor = 4;

using GpioController gpio = new();
using Dht11 sensor = new(_pinSensor, gpioController: gpio);

var temperature = sensor.Temperature.DegreesCelsius;
var humidity = sensor.Humidity.Percent;

var lines = new[]
{
    "",
    "DEVICE STAUTS",
    "-------------",
    $"LED: {(_ledOn ? "ON" : "OFF")}",
    $"Temperature: {temperature:0.#}°C",
    $"Humidity: {humidity:#.##}%",
    "",
    "Enter command (status/led/exit)"
};
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines));
```

I connected the voltage to +, ground to - and the data pin to the Gpio4 pin.

Would apreciate help with using that class if anybody knows how to do it correctly.

Cheers
garcipat

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the `TryReadHumidity` and the `TryReadTemperature` method of the Dht11 class. This methods return a bool where you can validate  the successful read of the sensor. But you will also receive a `RelativeHumidity` struct and a `Temperature` struct as a out parameter of the methods.

Example:

```
    Dht11 dht11 = new Dht11(26);

    if (!dht11.TryReadHumidity(out RelativeHumidity humidity))
    {
        _logger.LogError("Can't read humidity");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    if (!dht11.TryReadTemperature(out Temperature temperature))
    {
        _logger.LogError("Can't read temperature");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
    
    _logger.LogInformation("Humidity: {Humidity}%", humidity.Percent);
    _logger.LogInformation("Temperature: {Temperature}C", temperature.DegreesCelsius);
```